# What is the Practical difference between the Home screen and the Launcher screen?

Tags: nexus-one, home-screen, launcher

It seems that on my Nexus One, the home screen and launcher screen essentially serve the same purpose: Host application icons, allowing you to launch them.

Are there any other differences, other than the names and the way to reach these screens?

For example, can the launcher screen include widgets?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by launcher?

Comment: By "Launcher" do you mean the app drawer?

Comment: @Bryan @Al I am using the terminology in **nexusone-userguide.pdf**. I myself am relatively new to Android and so I don't even know what an "app drawer" is. I am in the process of reading the user's manual and I need to understand this issue.

Comment: the "app drawer" is the typically the on screen button at the bottom of your home screen.  It pulls up a list of all of your applications installed on your phone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is that the launcher screen contains all installed apps on your system. You cannot order it nor do anything but using the icons to access any application.

In the main screen you can:

- Add shortcuts to applications (icons
  like the ones in the launcher
  screen), you can place each icon in
  the place you want.
- Add widgets that provide rich
  functionalities like clocks,
  calendars or weather access.

If you want to compare your phone with a computer, launcher screen is the equivalent of “start menu” in windows, while the main screen(s) are the equivalent to the desktop.

Comment: Hmm, the app list in the TouchWiz UI can be customized, I didn't realize it couldn't be in the AOSP UI.